# Adding values to specific column in treeview Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I made a treeview, and I want to add values in first and second column and then the program needs to calculate the values that will put in third column when you press the ENTER button (I used events and binds). I do not know how to put values in the specific column in treeview , I always get this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I know how to insert values in every column at once, but I do not know how to insert only one value to a specific column, without changing the values in other columns.
This is the function that I wrote:

```
def PlannedCosPerSize(event):

    try:
        for child in tree.get_children():
            Size=round(float(tree.item(child,"values")[1]),2)
            PlannedCost=round(float(tree.item(child,"values")[2]),2)
            PlanCostPerSize=float(round(PlannedCost/Size,2))

            tree.insert("","end", values=(PlanCostPerSize)[4])

            print(PlanCostPerSize)


    except IndexError:
        Error=messagebox.showinfo("error","You have error")
        pass

tree.bind('<Return>', PlannedCosPerSize)  # validate with Enter
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do: `PlannedCostPerSize[4]`?

Comment: I'm trying to insert `PlannedCostPerSize` to column 3, so i wrote index [4].
I know that it's not the right code, but I tried something

Comment: have you read any documentation on the `insert` method? https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert

Comment: Yes I did, I didn't find the solution. I know how to insert values to all columns, but I do not know how to insert to only one (specific) column

Comment: I updated the question and I have changed the code a little bit. Please check it out and tell me if you can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `insert` method is creating a new item in the `Treeview` but what you want to do is editing an existing item, so this is not the method to use.

One possibility is to use the `set` method of the `Treeview` to either get or set the value in a specific column:

- `treeview.set(item, '#1')` will give you the value in the first column.
- `treeview.set(item, '#3', new_value)` will change the value of the third column into `new_value`.

You can also use the column's name (the one given in `columns=` when creating the `Treeview`) instead of `'#<column number>'`.

Another possibility is to use the `item` method:

- `old_values = treeview.item(item, 'values')` will give you the values of the item.
- `treeview.item(item, values=(old_values[0], old_values[1], new_value))` will change the last value of the item.

Documentation on the Treeview widget: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html

Comment: I managed to do what I tried with `set`, but it always inputs the result in the first row, even if I add values in other rows. Do you maybe know whats the problem?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this issue?