# Python adding a list to a slice of another list

Tags: python, list, slice, addition

Here's basic problem:

```
>>> listb = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
>>> slicea = slice(2,5)
>>> listb[slicea]
[3, 4, 5]
>>> lista = listb[slicea]
>>> lista
[3, 4, 5]
>>> listb[slicea] += lista
>>> listb
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

`listb` should be

```
[1, 2, 6, 8, 10, 6, 7]
```

But `3, 4, 5` was inserted after `3, 4, 5` not added to it.

---

## tl;dr

I have this code that's not working:

```
    self.lib_tree.item(song)['values'][select_values] = adj_list
    self.lib_tree.item(album)['values'][select_values] += adj_list
    self.lib_tree.item(artist)['values'][select_values] += adj_list
```

The full code is this:

```
def toggle_select(self, song, album, artist):

    # 'values' 0=Access, 1=Size, 2=Selected Size, 3=StatTime, 4=StatSize,
    #          5=Count, 6=Seconds, 7=SelSize, 8=SelCount, 9=SelSeconds
    # Set slice to StatSize, Count, Seconds
    total_values = slice(4, 7)       # start at index, stop before index
    select_values = slice(7, 10)     # start at index, stop before index

    tags = self.lib_tree.item(song)['tags']
    if "songsel" in tags:
        # We will toggle off and subtract from selected parent totals
        tags.remove("songsel")
        self.lib_tree.item(song, tags=(tags))
        # Get StatSize, Count and Seconds
        adj_list = [element * -1 for element in \
                    self.lib_tree.item(song)['values'][total_values]]
    else:    
        tags.append("songsel")
        self.lib_tree.item(song, tags=(tags))
        # Get StatSize, Count and Seconds
        adj_list = self.lib_tree.item(song)['values'][total_values]  # 1 past

    self.lib_tree.item(song)['values'][select_values] = adj_list
    self.lib_tree.item(album)['values'][select_values] += adj_list
    self.lib_tree.item(artist)['values'][select_values] += adj_list
    if self.debug_toggle < 10:
        self.debug_toggle += 1
        print('artist,album,song:',self.lib_tree.item(artist, 'text'), \
                                   self.lib_tree.item(album, 'text'), \
                                   self.lib_tree.item(song, 'text'))
        print('adj_list:',adj_list)
```

The `adj_list` has the correct values showing up in debug.

***How do I add a list of values to the slice of a list?***

Comment: That is not the full code. I have no idea what most of the data structures are. Please post an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MadPhysicist I made a scaled down generic verrsion. The original code is 5K lines and impractical to include it all.

Comment: Are you trying to add the values to each other, `numpy` style? Python sequences don't do that; you'll need `numpy` arrays if you want that to happen.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Exactly. Adding values from one list to the values in another list. I read about `numpy` but have never used it. I thought it was geared towards "scientific" applications and didn't think addition `2 + 2 = 4` was scientific.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: `2 + 2 = 4` is not. But `[2, 3, 4] + [2, 3, 4] = [4, 6, 8]` is in fact what `numpy` is built for. Scientific applications *benefit* from it, but at its core, it's just for vectorized number crunching.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for coming out of the "shadows" revealing how to add a "range" of elements :) If you can post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You seem to completely misunderstand the point of an MCVE. Please look at the link I sent you carefully. "original code" should have nothing to do with what you post here. Code here should be minimal example to represent your problem, not an incomplete excerpt of a full project.

Comment: @MadPhysicist As per my comment under accepted answer this turned out to be an XY problem. The real problem is tkinter trreeview's in ability to allow assigning list values as a splice. You need to use `.set` method on columns individually instead. You can only retrieve list values with a splice. But yes I did read the link and I had misunderstood your point initially. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you want is not a feature of any Python built-in type; `+` with built-in sequences means concatenation, not element-wise addition. But `numpy` arrays will do what you want, so I'd suggest looking into `numpy`. Simple example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([2,3,4], dtype=np.int64)
>>> b = np.array([5,6,7], dtype=np.int64)
>>> a += b
>>> a
array([ 7,  9, 11])
>>> print(a)
[ 7  9 11]
>>> print(a.tolist())
[7, 9, 11]
```

Note that the output (both `repr` and `str` forms) looks a little different from Python `list`s, but you can convert back to a plain Python `list` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turns out my problems go even deeper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024404/adding-values-to-specific-column-in-treeview-tkinter